# Google Earth Engine REST API Authentication from Ruby fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-contacts-api, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to use a service account to make an API request to [https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/{my-project}:listAssets?key={serviceKey}](https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/%7Bmy-project%7D:listAssets?key=%7BserviceKey%7D),
but I always get 401 unauthorized.

```
 url = "https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/{project-id}:listAssets?key=ServiceAccountKey"
endpoint = URI.parse(url)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(endpoint.to_s)

response = Net::HTTP.start(endpoint.host, endpoint.port, use_ssl: true) { |http| http.request(request) }
JSON.parse(response.body)
```

Comment: Try to elaborate. Explain what you did. Then show some code and where exactly you are getting which error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue in the past.
You need to be accepted/enrolled first by the Google EarthEngine team in order to access the API.

> Signup for Earth Engine. Once you have been accepted, you will receive an email with additional information.

To signup, follow instructions from the official Google docs [here](https://signup.earthengine.google.com/?hl=de).

It took 1 day in my case and I could then call the API smoothly.

EDIT: The HTTP 401 response you are getting indicates invalid authentication credentials. In my case, the app connects using a Service Account. I followed instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/service_account) and my app could connect smoothly to the Earth Engine. hope it helps

Comment: I'm already signed up to Google Earth Engine. I'm doing a REST API call from my app, I tried sending the key (the service key), I got 401. I tried to pass the client_id, I also got the same response 401.

Comment: just added more details in my answer with the way I got in. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I created a Service Account. However, I can't use ee.ServiceAccountCredentials as I'm doing this using Ruby on rails.

Comment: In your case, I would create a cloud function (GCP or AWS lambda) to handle all the Earth Engine API in Node.js (or Python) and I would let the Ruby on Rails side simply make HTTP calls to your cloud function. So, your intermediate EE custom-API is abstracted away from your user-facing app, handling credentials & custom EE-related logic.

Comment: I was able to properly authenticate the request and get a response back. I had to set the account credentials in the omniauth initializer file using `gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'` gem, and set the scope also which had to include the APIs scope mentioned in [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reference/rest/v1alpha/projects/listAssets). However I will try the approach you mentioned as I don't have access to (ee variable)  when doing the REST API calls.